# Можно ли использовать gulp-ejs динамично?

Tags: javascript, html, css, gulp, ejs

Есть проект, вёрстка админ-панели с многочисленными компонентами. Имеется папка компонентов, чтобы их использовать, использую **плагин gulp-ejs** и делаю   например так: `<%- include('../components/buttons/_success') %>` Естественно **у кнопки текст** везде, где инклудится данный компонент, одинаковый, а я **хочу сделать его текст динамичным**, например импортирую в навигацию и поменять текст. Как пример можно взять реакт, где вместо статичного текста компонента ставят props.title какой-нибудь. Помогите пожалуйста, как реализовать это с помощью gulp-ejs. Как уже догадались, проект собирается с помощью **сборщика gulp**, чистая верстка, **без каких-либо express-js**

Comment: А какой плагин вам компоненты в импорт превращает?

Comment: плагин gulp-ejs